# Find in a given directory, if there exist 2 files that have exactly the same content irrespective of their names

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

if the problem could be solved using a series of commands on the command line, it would be better for me than writing a script

Comment: Hi and welcome to Unix Stack Exchange. I think to do this, you would need to use the `diff` command. You would probably have to construct a `for` loop to compare each file in the directory to every other. Could do it with a fairly simple script.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in *; do for y in *; do [ "$x" = "$y" ] && continue; cmp -s "$x" "$y" && echo Same: "$x" and "$y"; done; done|head -1
```

Or, broken up a bit for readability:

```
for x in *
do 
  for y in *
  do 
    [ "$x" = "$y" ] && continue
    cmp -s "$x" "$y" && echo Same: "$x" and "$y"
  done
done | head -1
```

The `head` is just to keep the mirror reporting down ("a = b" and "b = a").

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum "{}" \; | awk 'seen[$1] { print "Duplicate file "$2" with hash "$1" at "seen[$1]" } ! seen[$1] {seen[$1]=$2}'
```

Comment: It says "Duplicate file xxx with hash yyy". That's right. But duplicate to _what_ file? But nicely scripted!

Comment: Tweaked to store the first filename found in the array for reference in the output.